# zLib inflate has empty result in some cases

Tags: c++, pdf, zlib, inflate, compression

My program processes PDF files and reads some streams out of them. There are also FlateEncoded streams in there. I use the "inflate()" method of zlib to decompress them.

This usually works really well with the following code:

```
static string FlateDecode(string s){

    int factor = 50;
    z_stream stream;
    while(true){
        char * out = new char[s.length()*factor];           

        stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
        stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
        stream.opaque = Z_NULL;
        stream.avail_in = s.length();
        stream.next_in = (Bytef*)s.c_str();
        stream.avail_out = s.length()*factor;
        stream.next_out = (Bytef*)out;
        inflateInit(&stream);
        inflate(&stream, Z_FINISH);
        inflateEnd(&stream);


        if(stream.total_out >= factor*s.length()){
            delete[] out;
            factor *= 2;
            continue;

        }
        string result;
        for(unsigned long i = 0; i < stream.total_out; i++){
            result += out[i];
        }

        delete[] out;
        return result;
    }
}
```

But inflate has an empty result for some streams. It´s not often, but it happens. Has someone an idea why?

The streams must be ok because all PDF readers read the PDF files correctly.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

I've uploaded the PDF and the stream so you can check it by your own.

[PDF](http://files.flashfan.ch/pdf/inflate/pdf.pdf)  -> The stream starts at byte 43296

[Stream](http://files.flashfan.ch/pdf/inflate/stream.txt)

**UPDATE 2**

I compared the streams that can´t be decompressed with the streams that can be decompressed. I've noticed an interesting thing: The working streams all begin with the 2 bytes H%. The problematic streams begin with ö>. Does anyone now what this means?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does " inflate has an empty result" mean ? (I'd guess it was inflate returning 0, but you don't check the return value of any of the inflate calls, which you **absolutely should** )

Comment: It means that when i inflate some data, the value of stream.total_out is 0, which means there is no output -> the length of the returned string is 0, too.

Comment: How sure are you that the input is actually 'inflatable'?  Have you tried outputting to file and confirming via command line that the input is actually valid?  Also, what is the return value of `inflate()`?

Comment: Yes I have extracted the stream to a new file and tested it with it. I've now checked the result of inflate(&stream, Z_FINISH), it returns -3 which means there is a data error. The strange thing is, that other programs can decode it... :S zlib bug?

Comment: To your latest update - all zlib streams should start with 0x78, 0x9c byte sequence ("zlib signature"). We have a piece of code that can accept both uncompressed and compressed data - it inspects the first two bytes to decide whether it is compressed.

Comment: @sharptooth And what is the "trick" to decompress also streams that don´t start with this byte sequence?

Comment: @FlashFan: Our code treats those streams as uncompressed and just passes them as is. But we know for sure that the stream is either uncompressed or compressed by zlib. In your case it might be some other compression/encoding as well.

Comment: I've read the zlib documenation here: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1950.html. The streams that can be decompressed match the documentation. The streams that can't be decompressed have somehow complete wrong header information... Has someone an idea why this can happen in PDF´s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zlib simply seems to not support all deflated streams found in PDF files.

Comment: It certainly can't be as simple as that! I mean, it's your question, you can answer it however you want, but that isn't really answering the question (i.e., "why?").

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't reinitialize the stream on each iteration. Initialize it before the loop and call `inflate()` inside the loop until it returns either `Z_OK` or  `Z_STREAM_END`.

Comment: You´re right! Thanks for the tip, even if this had nothing to do with the problem ;)

Comment: @FlashFan: I'm almost sure that's relevant to your problem. You try to feed the same data on each iteration.

Comment: I've already done it. But it returns Z_DATA_ERROR when it is called first.

Comment: @FlashFan: Could you please include the altered version of your code in the question?

Comment: @FlashFan: You still initialize and finalize the stream on each iteration.

Comment: This is required, because next_in and next_out changes in every iteration. calling inflateInit() and then specifying this values causes an error. Maybe I don´t understand what you mean... could you add the code to your answer and modify it?  ...but! inflate is called exactly once for this stream! So I don´t think your changes are the solution...

Comment: @FlashFan: You should only initialize the stream once, then set "avail in", "next in", "next out", "avail out" parameters, then call inflate(), then inspect the stream fields to find how much data was consumed and produced and adjust the stream fields.

Comment: This is what I'm doing at the moment. The loop is only for the case that the output array is too small to store the decoded data. In this case I increase the size of the output array and decode the data again. This needs a new initialization

Comment: @FlashFan: Yes, you're right. The problem might be that you use `std::string` and the data you tried to decompress contained a null character in the middle as user kem suggests in his answer.