# Inflation of pdf stream using zlib blank sometimes

Tags: c++, pdf, zlib, inflate, compression

I am a beginner programmer trying to inflate text stream from pdfs. I have adopted and slightly altered some open source code which uses zlib, and generally it works very well. However, I have been testing on some different pdfs lately and some of the inflated streams are returning blank. Could anybody advise me as to why?

I have come across this question below which seems to address the same problem but does not really give a definitive answer

[zLib inflate has empty result in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864339/zlib-inflate-has-empty-result-in-some-cases)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "zlib.h"

    int main()
    {
        //Discard existing output:
        //Open the PDF source file:
        std::ifstream filei("C:\\Users\\dpbowe\\Desktop\\PIDSearch\\P&ID.PDF", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);
        if (!filei) std::cout << "Error Opening Input File" << std::endl;

        //decoded output
        std::ofstream fileo;
        fileo.open("C:\\Users\\dpbowe\\Desktop\\Decoded.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ofstream::out);
        if (!fileother) std::cout << "Error opening output file" << std::endl;

        if (filei && fileo)
        {
            //Get the file length:
            long filelen = filei.tellg();   //fseek==0 if ok
            filei.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

            //Read the entire file into memory (!):
            char* buffer = new char [filelen];
            if (buffer == NULL) {fputs("Memory error", stderr); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
            filei.read(buffer,filelen);
            if (buffer == '\0') {fputs("Reading error", stderr); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

            bool morestreams = true;
            //Now search the buffer repeated for streams of data
            while (morestreams)
            {
                //Search for stream, endstream. Should check the filter of the object to make sure it if FlateDecode, but skip that for now!
                size_t streamstart = FindStringInBuffer (buffer, "stream", filelen);  //This is my own search function
                size_t streamend   = FindStringInBuffer (buffer, "endstream", filelen); //This is my own search function

                if (streamstart>0 && streamend>streamstart)
                {
                    //Skip to beginning and end of the data stream:
                    streamstart += 6;

                    if (buffer[streamstart]==0x0d && buffer[streamstart+1]==0x0a) streamstart+=2;
                    else if (buffer[streamstart]==0x0a) streamstart++;

                    if (buffer[streamend-2]==0x0d && buffer[streamend-1]==0x0a) streamend-=2;
                    else if (buffer[streamend-1]==0x0a) streamend--;

                    //Assume output will fit into 10 times input buffer:
                    size_t outsize = (streamend - streamstart)*10;
                    char* output = new char [outsize]; ZeroMemory(output, outsize);

                    //Now use zlib to inflate:
                    z_stream zstrm; ZeroMemory(&zstrm, sizeof(zstrm));

                    zstrm.avail_in = streamend - streamstart + 1;
                    zstrm.avail_out = outsize;
                    zstrm.next_in = (Bytef*)(buffer + streamstart);
                    zstrm.next_out = (Bytef*)output;

                    int rsti = inflateInit(&zstrm);
                    if (rsti == Z_OK)
                    {
                        int rst2 = inflate (&zstrm, Z_FINISH);
                        if (rst2 >= 0)
                        {
                            size_t totout = zstrm.total_out;

                            //Write inflated output to file "Decoded.txt"
                            fileother<<output;
                            fileother<<"\r\nStream End\r\n\r\n";
                        }
                        else std::cout<<"output uncompressed stream is blank"<<std::endl;
                    }
                    delete[] output; output=0;
                    buffer+= streamend + 7;
                    filelen = filelen - (streamend+7);
                }
                else
                {
                    morestreams = false;
                    std::cout<<"End of File"<<std::endl;
                }
            }
            filei.close();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "File Could Not Be Accessed\n";
        }
        if (fileo) fileo.close();
    }
```

Comment: Why deflate it yourself? There are plenty of good PDF parsing libraries out there that will do this for you and saves you the hassle of debugging these kinds of things.  Just a suggestion!

Comment: Your code looks very much like some very naïve text extraction attempts posted on codeproject. These attempts all assume one merely needs to find some some pairs of `stream` and `endstream` without taking PDF structure into account and inflate what is inbetween. They are very prone to find such "pairs" not really making up the start and end of a stream. Furthermore they completely ignore that streams **a** are not necessarily deflated after all, and **b** may be encrypted and require decryption before any inflating or other decoding attempt.

Comment: Apart from what @mkl said (which most likely is the problem here), also note that `//Assume output will fit into 10 times input buffer:` *will* turn around and bite you at some time in the future. I've had that happen to me a couple of times.

Comment: Thought just looking for stream and endstream seemed a bit too simple. The pdfs I'm trying to decode are engineering drawings and do get a bit complicated so it would make sense that it's a structural issue. A good little exercise to learn the basics behind pdfs but I suppose using something like Xpdf would be a more sensible approach for me. Thanks for the help guys!